# Python code for searching .txt file. Print lines containing words in parantheses

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I think my regex function is wrong. I get an error. I want the program to read the .txt file line by line and print only lines which don't contain words in parenthesis. 
Here is the code I used.

```
import os
infile=open("/Users/Julio/Desktop/database.txt", "r")

for line in infile:
    if not re.search('(')

     print(line, end='')

infile.close()
```

Comment: Read a basic [regex tutorial first](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: Thanks, I think that will help

Comment: I'm still not sure how to edit the code to make it work. Can someone point out what is wrong?

Comment: @JulioHans I do believe you have to add a second argument to re.search(). Try it, but I'm not too sure. `re.search('(', infile)`.

Comment: The title and third sentence contradict each other as to whether you want to print lines that do or do not contain whatever.  However, code difference will only be a `not` or not.

Answer (score 1):

For something as simple matching a single character, why not just avoid regex and do something like:

```
with open("database.txt","rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "(" not in line:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution not using Regex, and looks for single words in parenthesis. Try to avoid using regex unless you have to.

```
for line in file_text.split("\n"):
    for word in line.split(" "):
        paren_flag = True if word[0] == "(" and word[len(word) - 1] == ")" else False
    if not paren_flag:
        print(line)
```

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

***Note:*** I hope you were asking how to look for single words in parenthesis, because your question was/is unclear at the time of answering.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for just "(". The parenthesis itself.

Comment: @JulioHans Ah, in that case you should edit you question to make that a little clearer. Maybe *"I want to see if a bracket is in a line"*?